# webbrowser modul windows service?

Tags: python, windows, service

my example code:

```
  import pyautogui
  import webbrowser
  import time
  webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://127.0.0.1:8080/scripts/a.php")

  time.sleep(5)

  pyautogui.hotkey('tab')

  pyautogui.typewrite('  lololo',interval=0.25)

  pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

How can I start the module of webbrowser modul as aservice of windows ?